# Htaccess redirection exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rules in my htaccess in order to force https navigation:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I want to add an exception for a page let's name it 'page.php'

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a negative condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page\.php$` will exclude `/page.php` from this rule.

There is another way of doing so using negative condition in `RewriteRule` itself:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^page\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```