# Redirect all www or non www page to https://www except one page

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to enforce `https://www.` on all of my pages except `hotels.php`.
My current code below is adding `www.` twice, i.e. `https://www.www.example.com`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/hotels.php\/
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/hotels.php\/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Let me know what I am missing here which causing issue.
Thanks

Comment: Already been asked and answered in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @jasie Please vote to close / flag as duplicate with the apropriate Q/A.

Comment: Rewriting configured in .htaccess “loops” until no rules match any more. _After_ you have externally redirected to `https://www.example.com/foo` already (or if you requested this to begin with), your first set of conditions & rules redirects again - but the `HTTP_HOST` variable now contains `www.example.com` already, to which you add another `www.` in front. You need an additional condition in that place that checks if the host name does not start with `www.` already, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4958847/10283047 for an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess redirection exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037601/htaccess-redirection-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if www is in the request URI as you check HTTPS. Try this:

```
//If has not www and it's not a subdomain adds www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

//If has not https and it's not hotels.php add https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/hotels.php\/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: all is working fine with this but hotels.php still loading with https:// not redirecting it to http://

Answer (score 2):

Try these rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force https:// for all except your desired URLs    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/hotels.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// for your desired URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /hotels.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a master with Htaccess regex, bit this works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps! There's lot of answers to this on StackOverflow... pretty sure that probably where I got the above!